# is there a way to turn if statement in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I've got this code

```
if (header.classList.contains("capricorn")) {
    //star sign description
    para.innerHTML = starSign.Capricorn;
  } else if (header.classList.contains("aquarius")) {
    para.innerHTML = starSign.Aquarius;
  } else if (header.classList.contains("pisces")) {
    para.innerHTML = starSign.Pisces;
```

I want to turn it in a switch statement, is that possible?

Comment: yes thank you. that's what i thought i could do instead, i'm gonna try it now

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterizing your checks instead, based on the properties of `starSign` object:

```
function chooseSign(classList, signs) {
  return signs.find(s => classList.contains(s.toLowerCase());
}
```

... and using it accordingly:

```
const sign = chooseSign(header.classList, Object.keys(starSign));
if (sign) {
  para.innerHTML = starSign[sign];
}
```

I assumed `starSign` is a collection of texts with only 12 keys. If that's not the case, consider making a separate array out of those.

---

In general, when you have a looooong series of if - else if - else if checks doing essentially the same stuff over and over, think about using separate function for the same purpose. Not only this gives you a chance to simplify the code (like in this example), but also isolates the business logic decision making your code both more readable and more testable.

Comment: thanks very much, very helpful! that's what i was trying to do, make my code simplier since i have lots of If statement